# Some problem with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have some problem about use biblatex with my document. I add package like this:

```
\usepackage[
           backend = biber,
           bibencoding = utf8,
           sorting = ynt,
           maxcitenames = 3,
           style = numeric-comp,
           ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

And my bib file like this:

```
@article{Hankamer2007,
  title={Electron crystallography of membrane proteins},
  author={Hankamer, Ben and Glaeser, Robert and Stahlberg, Henning},
  journal={Journal of structural biology},
  volume={160},
  number={3},
  pages={263},
  year={2007},
  publisher={NIH Public Access}
}

@article{Weik2000,
  title={Specific chemical and structural damage to proteins produced by    synchrotron radiation},
  author={Weik, Martin and Ravelli, Raimond BG and Kryger, Gitay and  McSweeney, Sean and Raves, Maria L and Harel, Michal and Gros, Piet and Silman,  Israel and Kroon, Jan and Sussman, Joel L},
  journal={Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
  volume={97},
  number={2},
  pages={623--628},
  year={2000},
  publisher={National Acad Sciences}
}
```

etc. I have 30 sources in my bib file. Everything was good and worked fine. But now I can't find a key-tips for the `\cite{}` command argument:

[image: Previously, there were tips for the <code>\cite{}</code> command argument]

This is the first small trouble. Now, if I want to add the following source (e. g. 31, 32 etc.) and link to them, I'll get the bug after compilation:

[image: Bug after compilation.]

I don't see the number of article in my source list :( How to fix it? Please, help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could we have a fully compilable (non) working example, in order to test?

Comment: Since you're using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) you need to compile using the sequence (pdf)LaTeX > biber > (pdf)LaTeX > (pdf)LaTeX, as suggested in [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/5764).

Comment: The first part of this is an editor question (looks like TeXmaker to me, but someone else will have to verify. The second part of the question is a trivial typo – double-check that `herman1976` exists as a citekey in your bib file. Without a complete MWE it's impossible to provide any definitive help.